Backend DB : 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
I am learning to use vu.js on my own. So my knowledge so far is nearly nonexistent. I tried to make sense of posts that have the same issue, but I could not find my solution.
First, here is my problem:
I am trying to add a snippet with its tags to a database.
There are 3 tables : tags, snippets, and snippet_tags.
I have a function that creates a snippet, and it works fine when i do not use tags.
I have a function that associate tags to snippets and it works fine on its own.
Now, when I try to combine then, it does not work so I can not create a snippet with tags.
Here is my DB schema:
CREATE TABLE public.snippet_tags (
    snippet_id integer NOT NULL,
    tag_id integer NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE public.snippets (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    title character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    content text NOT NULL,
    category_id integer NOT NULL,
    subcategory_id integer,
    public boolean,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    language character varying(50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE public.tags (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50) NOT NULL
);

Here is the snippet_controller.py  content :
import logging
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from flask import request, jsonify
from app import db
from app.models.snippet import Snippet
from app.models.tag import Tag

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

def create_snippet():
    data = request.get_json()
    title = data.get('title')
    description = data.get('description')
    content = data.get('content')
    category_id = data.get('category_id')
    subcategory_id = data.get('subcategory_id')
    public = data.get('public', False)
    user_id = data.get('user_id')
    language = data.get('language')
    tags = data.get('tags', [])  # Use tags from request body

    if not all([title, description, content, category_id, user_id, language]):
        logger.error("Required fields are missing")
        return jsonify({"error": "All required fields must be provided"}), 400

    try:
        logger.debug("Creating new snippet")
        new_snippet = Snippet(
            title=title,
            description=description,
            content=content,
            category_id=category_id,
            subcategory_id=subcategory_id,
            public=public,
            user_id=user_id,
            language=language
        )

        db.session.add(new_snippet)
        db.session.commit()
        logger.debug(f"New snippet created with ID: {new_snippet.id}")

        # Call associate_tags function to handle tag association
        response = associate_tags(new_snippet.id, tags)
        if response[1] != 200:
            return response

        return jsonify(new_snippet.to_dict()), 201
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        logger.error(f'SQLAlchemyError: {str(e)}', exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        db.session.rollback()  # Ensure rollback on any exception
        logger.error(f'Unhandled Exception: {str(e)}', exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500



def get_snippets():
    try:
        snippets = Snippet.query.all()
        return jsonify([snippet.to_dict() for snippet in snippets])
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500

def get_snippet(snippet_id):
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.query.get_or_404(snippet_id)
        return jsonify(snippet.to_dict())
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500

def update_snippet(snippet_id):
    data = request.get_json()
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.query.get_or_404(snippet_id)
        snippet.title = data.get('title', snippet.title)
        snippet.description = data.get('description', snippet.description)
        snippet.content = data.get('content', snippet.content)
        snippet.category_id = data.get('category_id', snippet.category_id)
        snippet.subcategory_id = data.get('subcategory_id', snippet.subcategory_id)
        snippet.public = data.get('public', snippet.public)
        snippet.language = data.get('language', snippet.language)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(snippet.to_dict()), 200
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500

def delete_snippet(snippet_id):
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.query.get_or_404(snippet_id)
        db.session.delete(snippet)
        db.session.commit()
        return '', 204
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500

def associate_tags(snippet_id, tags):
    try:
        snippet = Snippet.query.get_or_404(snippet_id)
        snippet.tags = []  # Clear existing tags

        for tag_name in tags:
            logger.debug(f"Processing tag: {tag_name}")
            tag = Tag.query.filter_by(name=tag_name).first()
            if not tag:
                logger.debug(f"Creating new tag: {tag_name}")
                tag = Tag(name=tag_name)
                db.session.add(tag)
                db.session.commit()  # Commit new tag immediately

            logger.debug(f"Appending tag: {tag_name} -> Tag instance: {tag}")
            snippet.tags.append(tag)

        db.session.commit()
        logger.debug("Tags associated and committed to DB")
        return jsonify({"message": "Tags associated successfully"}), 200
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        logger.error(f'SQLAlchemyError: {str(e)}', exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        db.session.rollback()  # Ensure rollback on any exception
        logger.error(f'Unhandled Exception: {str(e)}', exc_info=True)
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500

def get_snippets_by_tag(tag_id):
    try:
        tag = Tag.query.get_or_404(tag_id)
        snippets = [snippet.to_dict() for snippet in tag.snippets]
        return jsonify(snippets), 200
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e.orig)}), 500

Then in the snippet.py you will see that:
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Snippet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'snippets'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'), nullable=False)
    subcategory_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subcategories.id'))
    public = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    language = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    # Relationships
    category = relationship('Category', backref=db.backref('snippets', lazy=True))
    subcategory = relationship('Subcategory', backref=db.backref('snippets', lazy=True))
    user = relationship('User', backref=db.backref('snippets', lazy=True))
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary='snippet_tags', back_populates='snippets')

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'title': self.title,
            'description': self.description,
            'content': self.content,
            'category_id': self.category_id,
            'subcategory_id': self.subcategory_id,
            'public': self.public,
            'user_id': self.user_id,
            'created_at': self.created_at.isoformat() if self.created_at else None,
            'language': self.language,
            'tags': [tag.name for tag in self.tags]  # Include tag names in the dictionary
        }

class Favorite(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'favorites'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    snippet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('snippets.id'), primary_key=True)

    # Relationships
    user = relationship('User', backref=db.backref('favorites', cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
    snippet = relationship('Snippet', backref=db.backref('favorites', cascade="all, delete-orphan")) 

Can you explain my error and provide the correction?
The only error I see in docker is : : 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
UPDATE here is the Docker backend logs:
2024-07-13 12:26:49 INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
2024-07-13 12:26:49  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
2024-07-13 12:26:49  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
2024-07-13 12:26:49  * Running on http://192.168.128.4:5000
2024-07-13 12:26:49 INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
2024-07-13 12:26:49 INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
2024-07-13 12:26:50 WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
2024-07-13 12:26:50 INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 837-231-156
2024-07-13 12:26:49  * Serving Flask app 'server.py'
2024-07-13 12:26:49  * Debug mode: on
2024-07-13 12:28:17 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py:22: SAWarning: relationship 'SnippetTag.snippet' will copy column snippets.id to column snippet_tags.snippet_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Snippet.tags' (copies snippets.id to snippet_tags.snippet_id), 'Tag.snippets' (copies snippets.id to snippet_tags.snippet_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="snippets,tags"' to the 'SnippetTag.snippet' relationship. (Background on this warning at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/qzyx) (This warning originated from the `configure_mappers()` process, which was invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)
2024-07-13 12:28:17   return cls.query_class(
2024-07-13 12:28:17 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py:22: SAWarning: relationship 'SnippetTag.tag' will copy column tags.id to column snippet_tags.tag_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Snippet.tags' (copies tags.id to snippet_tags.tag_id), 'Tag.snippets' (copies tags.id to snippet_tags.tag_id). If this is not the intention, consider if these relationships should be linked with back_populates, or if viewonly=True should be applied to one or more if they are read-only. For the less common case that foreign key constraints are partially overlapping, the orm.foreign() annotation can be used to isolate the columns that should be written towards.   To silence this warning, add the parameter 'overlaps="snippets,tags"' to the 'SnippetTag.tag' relationship. (Background on this warning at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/qzyx) (This warning originated from the `configure_mappers()` process, which was invoked automatically in response to a user-initiated operation.)
2024-07-13 12:28:17   return cls.query_class(
2024-07-13 12:28:17 INFO:werkzeug:192.168.128.1 - - [13/Jul/2024 10:28:17] "POST /api/tags HTTP/1.1" 201 -
2024-07-13 12:28:37 ERROR:app:Unhandled Exception: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
2024-07-13 12:28:37 INFO:werkzeug:192.168.128.1 - - [13/Jul/2024 10:28:37] "POST /api/snippets HTTP/1.1" 500 -


Can you share the full stacktrace?

@Mureinik, I just update the code above

This type of error is caused by passing a plain python object (a str, in  this case) when SQLAlchemy is expecting an ORM entity.  Can you run this outside of docker and try to get a proper traceback?  Remove all the exception handling if necessary while doing this.
